# ASP.NET Master Page Content Page's IDs all changed, breaking CSS based on original element IDs? Are you kidding me

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, content-pages

ASP.NET Master Page Content Page's elements all seem to be having their ID's changed or prepended by the ASP.NET page renderer.

This breaks all CSS styles based on the original element IDs.

Is this seriously how it works?  If so, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can specify the `ClientIDMode` set it to static.

*examples*:

**Client Side**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.ID = "TextBox1";
txtBox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static
```

By setting it to static...

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

---

**Update** *thanks to* @Chris Lively *for the additional info*

---

**Page Level**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoEventWireup="true"...
```

**Application Level**

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
</system.web>
```

*references*:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx
- http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx

Comment: Note this was introduced in ASP.net 4.0

Comment: Also, it can be controlled in the web.config for the entire project in the <pages> section.

Comment: @Chris, I was not aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the `ClientID` property instead of the `ID` property.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure this would help in the case of a linked stylesheet

Comment: @Jon P, It would.  The ClientID generates the DOM element's ID, which is what is formatted by the linked stylesheet.