# input "id" and "name" changes when set runat=server from

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In my form I need to insert different inputs of type "hidden".
The inputs must be html controls with "name" and "id's". Because I send this form to a external url.

For the validation I do runat=server in a hidden input and then I can use requiredfieldvalidator.

But the problem is when I look in the source after visiting the page the name is changed. for example

```
<input type="hidden" name="hotelIdform" value="" runat="server" id="hotelIdform">
```

changed to

```
 <input name="ctl00$ctl00$Master_Body$child_center_content$hotelIdform" type="hidden" id="hotelIdform" value="b4ba78fc-0b62-4809-9dca-000972573139" />
```

and i used ClientIDMode="Static" , just ID is okay

please help me

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Master pages and not using static client ID. Thus, ASP.NET is changing the ID while it compiling the page.

You need to set `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.

Please refer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494130/asp-net-master-page-content-pages-ids-all-changed-breaking-css-based-on-origin)

Comment: when set ClientIDMode="Static"  , just ID value is okay but Name not changed