# Master Page Changes ID of Elements

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I use JavaScript and am trying to use more JQuery. Anyway I never liked the way Master Pages change the ID's of my elements. So when I use getElementById("MyElement") it fails to find the element. So I hit F5 and do a view source and then copy the new ID of the element and it works.

My Question...
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: yes, there is a better way, instead of `getElementById("MyElement")` do `getElementById("<%= MyElement.ClientID %>")`. it will return the dynamically generated ID

Comment: Thanks; just what I was looking for. It uses that old classic asp syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ClientIDMode` and `ClientID` of your server control, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ClientID="MyTextBox" />
```

Now you can reference the textbox in jQuery or plain old JavaScript via the `MyTextBox` ID selector.

Comment: WAIT! ClientID doesn't pop up for me, but ClientIDMode does. I'm using 4.5 framework

Comment: <system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
</system.web>

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494130/asp-net-master-page-content-pages-ids-all-changed-breaking-css-based-on-origin