# Hiding a dynamically created label using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I'm creating some textboxes and labels dynamically and am trying to hide/show them via JQuery but can't get the JQuery working. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code behind:

```
TableCell td4 = new TableCell();

Label l2 = new Label();

l2.ID = "lbSell" + dp.dSellAutoID.ToString();
l2.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dp.dSellPrice), 2).ToString();
l2.Visible = false;
td4.Controls.Add(l2);

TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();

tb1.ID = "tbSell" + dp.dSellAutoID.ToString();
tb1.Width = 50;
tb1.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dp.dSellPrice), 2).ToString();
td4.Controls.Add(tb1);
tr.Cells.Add(td4);
```

And here's the JS:

```
function editRow(rowID) {
    //alert(rowID);
    $('#' + 'lbSell' + rowID).show();
    $('#' + 'tbSell' + rowID).hide();
}
```

Comment: show us where you call `editRow`

Comment: editRow is called via a dynamically created label and is firing and giving the correct rowID ie:
    l1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "editRow(" + dp.dSellAutoID.ToString() + ")");

Comment: Inspect your HTML and check what's value of ID is there.

Comment: OK.. it's rendered with a prefixed of 'main_'... i.e: "main_tbSell182"..
My knowledge in this space is vague.. what dictates this prefix?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using master pages? In that case, the ID changes while the page is being rendered. To prevent it, you can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the page directive

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" MasterPageFile="~/epinet.master" %>
```

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5494142/5746368

Comment: Yeah, using master pages.. are there any drawbacks in using the ClientIDMode="Static" approach? Or can I count on having 'MAIN' prefixed to controls sitting under the masterpage structure?

Comment: I don't find any drawback in setting ClientIDMode="static". I prefer doing it so that others can understand/debug my Javascript/jQuery without getting confused.

Comment: You may also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx for more details on ClientIDMode Property